# how to make logstash read kannel log

Tags: permissions, logs, group

I got logstash installed on ubuntu 12.04 using the apt repository. But logstash is not reading any document. In logstash log there are the following:

```
{:timestamp=>"2014-08-01T22:06:09.722000+0000", :message=>"failed to open /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log: Permission denied - /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log", :level=>:warn}
```

I have checked the permissions on the file :

```
$ ls -lh /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
-rw-r----- 1 kannel adm 42M Aug  2 00:14 /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
```

So I added logstash user to adm group with `usermod -a -G root logstash` and that didn't help. I have even added it to root but it still doesn't work. I am at the end of my wits.

Comment: Did you restart the service?

Comment: no , that would have to be planned since it's a production service. But I didn't think it will need a restart

Comment: The user needs to relogin after changing its groups. It's one of the reasons commands such as [`newgrp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/newgrp.1.html) exist.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the kernel is concerned, a process runs as a user¹ and one or more group. Once the process is started, it won't acquire more groups. A process inherits its user and group(s) from the process that calls it.

The notion of a user belonging to a group is managed by user administration tools, and it's the login program that bestows group memberships onto the process that it starts. Thus, when you add a user to a group, this only takes effect in login sessions started afterwards, not in already-ongoing sessions.

Daemons don't go through an interactive login process and are usually started as one particular user and group. Often the group isn't even read from the accounts database but hard-coded in the daemon's startup script next to the user name. So adding the `logstash` user to the `adm` group won't help you; what you need to do is change the logstash startup script to run logstash with `adm` as an additional group. How do do that depends on how the startup script is written. In any case this will require restarting the logstash service.

Alternatively, you can change the access control list of the log file to allow the logstash process to use it. For example, to allow the `logstash` user to read the kannel log file:

```
setfacl -m u:logstash:r /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
```

and maybe also

```
setfacl -m u:logstash:rx /var/log/kannel
```

Note that this may be only a temporary solution, as rotating the log may reinitialize its permissions. For this approach you'll probably need to change the configuration of the program that (re)creates the log file.

¹  <sub>Two users (real and effective) but the real UID isn't relevant in this answer.</sub>